# Using unzip_file() to get contents of file

Tags: uploads, attachments, ziparchive

With each post, I save a zip folder as an attachment containing a json file with large amount of data. When looping through posts, I need to open this folder and retrieve the contents of json file but I can't get this to work.

I'm running my wordpress installation on xampp and I've made sure that all users have full control of the xampp folder and subfolders

```
global $post;
global $wp_filesystem;


while ( $messages->have_posts() ) : 
    $messages->the_post();
$pid = get_the_ID();
$fileExt = ".json";
$folderExt = ".zip";
$msgData = get_attached_media( 'application', $pid );
$msgData = array_values($msgData);
$attachID = $msgData[0]->ID;
$dataTitle = $msgData[0]->post_title;
$fileName = $dataTitle . $fileExt;
$folderName = $dataTitle . $folderExt;
$folder = $msgData[0]->guid;
WP_Filesystem();
$destination = wp_upload_dir();
$destination_path = $destination['path'];
$unzipfile = unzip_file( $destination_path .'/'. $fileName, $destination_path);
if ( $unzipfile ) {
  echo 'Successfully unzipped the file!';
  var_dump($unzipfile); 
  $msgDataContents = file_get_contents($folder .'/'. $fileName);
  var_dump($msgDataContents);     
} else {
  echo 'There was an error unzipping the file.';       
}
```

The name of the zip and json file are the same.

I have confirmed that the $folder returns the correct url of the zip going to that url downloads the zip containing a json file with the correct content.

I think I'm making mistakes with paths but I've tried many. The first var_dump returns bool(true) and the second returns bool(false). What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can possibly [stream the file directly from the .zip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php), if that would work? Or if it's just a single file in the .zip you could use .gz instead which might have better support. I assume this is too much data to put in the database though, or store uncompressed on disk?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this though. What errors do you get - a file missing at a certain point? You should be able to add trace to this code to see what's going wrong, or just look at the filesystem afterwards since you're not cleaning anything up. You also might want to extract to somewhere else outside the WordPress folder e.g. /tmp or a new folder under /var perhaps, depending on how large the files are I guess.

Comment: Can you post the gz method as an answer? I tried that but it won't save as attachment and I added support for it as mime type just as I did zip.

Comment: If you mean you want me to figure out the missing details then I don't have time right now - sorry. Maybe later.